# How to sort solr suggestion based on length of the term

Tags: solr

I'm using following searchcomponent in my application for suggestion

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
 <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">term</str>
    <str name="payloadField">payload</str>
    <str name="contextField">vendor</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_autocomplete</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

When I try to hit suggest api http://localhost:8983/solr/primary/suggest?indent=on&suggest.q=apple&wt=json

I'm getting response like

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":6},
"suggest":{"suggester":{
  "apple":{
    "numFound":20,
    "suggestions":[{
        "term":"B Natural Apple Awe Juice",
        "weight":0,
        "payload":""},
      {
        "term":" Apple Awe Juice",
        "weight":0,
        "payload":""},
      {
        "term":" Apple",
        "weight":0,
        "payload":""},
      {
        "term":" B Natural Apple",
        "weight":0,
        "payload":""},
      {
        "term":" Apple Awe",
        "weight":0,
        "payload":""},
      {
        "term":" Apple Juice",
        "weight":0,
        "payload":""} ...
```

But I have to get based on term length or score like.

```
apple
apple awe
apple juice
apple awe juice
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Good question. I want the same thing; strange that no one has answered it for over two years. I guess I could index the field length and use that length field for sortField, but it would be nice if there were a simpler way.